# Search Records From Array of Object - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating a search filter for my array of objects so let's say I have an array of object

```
let arr = [{'name': 'mn zx abc'}, {'name': 'zx mn'}, {'name': 'mnzx'}]
```

now if i search for `zx` than it should return me result like

```
[{'name': 'mn zx abc'}, {'name': 'zx mn'}]
```

note than last object `{'name': 'mnzx'}` the `zx` is coming in between so i don't want that, hope you understands my problem

here is the code -

```js
let arr = [{'name': 'mn zx abc'}, {'name': 'zx mn'}, {'name': 'mnzx'}];

let searchedTerm = 'zx';

let result = arr.filter(data => {
    if (data.name.charAt(0) === searchedTerm.charAt(0)) {
        return true;
    }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is that you appear to be expecting us to do the coding for you... that's not how stackoverflow works.  You need to prove you've tried doing this yourself by providing a [mcve] (with a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) if possible) in your question. Please have a read of the [help] and the [ask] section in particular

Comment: Please try to upload the code which you have tried. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to identify objects where the name string contains a particular "word" as opposed to just particular characters.

One simple way to approach this would be to split the name field into words and then check the split list for the search term. If your words are delimited by whitespace, you could do `"mn zx abc".split(/\s+/)` for example to get `["mn", "zx", "abc"]`. `/\s+/` is a regular expression which matches one or more whitespace characters, so splitting on this leaves us with just the groups of non-whitespace characters.

We can then check for the search term's presence in the list using `indexOf`.

Here's a full example:

```
function matches(obj, searchTerm) { return obj.name.split(/\s+/).indexOf(searchTerm) >= 0; }

let arr = [{'name': 'mn zx abc'}, {'name': 'zx mn'}, {'name': 'mnzx'}];
let result = arr.filter(obj => matches(obj, "zx"));
```

Comment: hey. what happens if the searched term is 'mn' and the code which you shows will work for that also if the name is 'mnzx' so it should also include that name, where in your code its not including

Comment: I want a solution like in our android phone we can search a contact from the first name or last name so let's say I have saved a contact name like 'Shailesh Gehlot' so if I search like 'sha' or 'geh' it should show me 'Shailesh Gehlot' contact, whereas if i have contact name 'brashae mishra' even if searched term 'sha' is there in this name it should not include that name and do not show me that contact. let me know if u want me to elaborate more. thanks

Comment: @ShaileshGehlot any permutation of this kind of functionality can be pretty straightforward, but it's hard to tell the precise behavior you want from your examples (for example, do you want a search of "geh sha" to return "Shailesh Gehlot" or not? Do you want case-sensitivity? My suggestion would be to break the problem down and just focus on writing a matches function like the one above that fits the logic you're imagining.

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach it using a regular expression...

```js
// Your original array
let arr = [{'name': 'mn zx abc'}, {'name': 'zx mn'}, {'name': 'mnzx'}]

// Your original search term
let searchedTerm = 'zx';

// A new RegExp object which looks for your search term with a space before it (with case-insensitivity)
let searchRE = new RegExp(" " + searchedTerm, "i");

let result = arr.filter(data => {
    // Test to see if your data.name (with an additional space before it) matches
    return searchRE.test(" " + data.name);
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression with word boundary in `array#filter` to get all `name` with `zx`.

```js
let arr = [{'name': 'mn zx abc'}, {'name': 'zx mn'}, {'name': 'mnzx'}],
    searchedTerm = 'zx',
    result = arr.filter(({name}) => new RegExp( `\\b${searchedTerm}\\b`, "i").test(name));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the array using [`RegExp.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) with *word boundary `(\b)`*:

```js
let arr = [{'name': 'mn zx abc'}, {'name': 'zx mn'}, {'name': 'mnzx'}, {'name': 'zxmn'}, {'name': 'abczx mn'}];

const output = arr.filter(obj => /\bzx\b/.test(obj.name));

console.log(output);
```